# Flink S3 Write Fails Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chains

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

When I use flinks streaming API to write to S3:

```
// Set StreamExecutionEnvironment
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

// Set checkpoints in ms
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

// Add source (input stream)
DataStream<String> dataStream = StreamUtil.getDataStream(env, params);

// Sink to S3 Bucket
dataStream.writeAsText("s3a://test-flink/test.txt").setParallelism(1);
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
```

My configuration is:

```
# flink --version
Version: 1.3.1, Commit ID: 1ca6e5b
```

The Hadoop config directory was added to flink-conf.yaml

```
# cat flink/config/flink-conf.yaml | head -n1
fs.hdfs.hadoopconf: /root/hadoop-config
```

The rest of the content of flink-conf.yaml is identical to the release version.

The following was added to /root/hadoop-config/core-site.xml

```
# cat  /root/hadoop-config/core-site.xml
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.buffer.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
    <value>MY_ACCESS_KEY</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
    <value>MY_SECRET_KEY</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

The JAR’s aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar, hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar, httpclient-4.2.5.jar, httpcore-4.2.5.jar where added to flink/lib/ from http://apache.mirror.anlx.net/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.7.4/hadoop-2.7.4.tar.gz

```
# ls flink/lib/
aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
flink-dist_2.11-1.3.1.jar
flink-python_2.11-1.3.1.jar
flink-shaded-hadoop2-uber-1.3.1.jar
hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar
httpclient-4.2.5.jar
httpcore-4.2.5.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar
```

Note the aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar is 1.7.4 and not 1.7.2 as it is in the docs [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/aws.html#set-s3-filesystem)

pom.xml has the following build dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-filesystem_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

My reference was the (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/aws.html#set-s3-filesystem)

I am able to write to the S3 bucket using the credentials in core-site.xml with awscli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used DataStream API to write to S3, in my case the core-site.xml is actually present in the jar with the same configurations. 
Can you please try this approach.

The error occurs when the S3 API is not able to get the credentials from any provider as described in the below link

There are other approaches defined here to provide the credentials: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: Thanks Vinay, after `jar xf jar-file` the JAR file, and then `find . -name "*.xml"`, I can only locate ./core-default.xml, updating this file does not resolve the issue, am I missing something?

Comment: Should the `core-site.xml` be placed in the root of the jar or else where?

Comment: This means the node on which you are running is not configured correctly. Can you please check if there is .aws/credentials file on the node you are running the flink job. If this is not there you will have to run aws s3 configure command as shown here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/

Comment: Yes, the core-site should be kept in src/main/resources, so it will go to the root when jar is created

Comment: Yes, `/root/.aws/credentials/` is present of the node that is running the flink job, and I can use `awscli` from this node to read/write to s3.

Comment: That is strange, can you please try setting the creds as env variables as it is given in the credentials link and run the pipeline again

Comment: Check this link if you want to set the Credentials provider in core-site

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#S3A_Authentication_methods

Comment: After adding `core-site.xml` to `src/main/resource/` and using `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key` as the properties it worked! @vinay your the man!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/reference/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) as it will work both locally and over AWS EMR / EC2 / ECS.

Instead of just looking for your default credentials file (`~/.aws/credentials`), it will also look at common environment variables, java system properties, other common sources. See the [full list and precise lookup sequence here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html).

If it can help, here's the full contents of `src/main/resources/core-site.xml`:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3.impl</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider</name>
    <value>com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.buffer.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```